# jQuery dataTables : How to add new row (with action links for specific column)

Tags: jquery, datatables

The first column of the datatable is a hidden column, the last column has two action links.

```
    <table id="ruleFourTable" class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="display: none">ID</th>
                <th><a>RetailerName</a></th>
                <th><a>BeginDate</a></th>
                <th><a>EndDate</a></th>
                <th><a>Remark</a></th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr style="display: none">
                <td name="ID" style="display: none"></td>
                <td name="RetailerName"></td>
                <td name="Begin"></td>
                <td name="End"></td>
                <td name="Description"></td>
                <td name="__actionLink"><a class="actionLink edit">Edit</a>    <a class="actionLink delete">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I use the following code to dynamically add a new row into datatable.

```js
theTable.dataTable().fnAddData(data);
```

I got an warnning like 'DataTables warning Requested unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row'. Actually I got a new row inserted finally with the boring warnning. Any anyone comment on this issue, or how to programmatically insert new row?

Comment: What does `data` contain?

Comment: billyonecan, it is json data with all required fields. I traced the data as below Rule4ModalController updateModel - Create RuleID: 0, RetailerID: 29, RetailerName: a retailer, TypeCode: 4, TypeName: undefined, Begin: 2013-04-02T16:00:00.000Z, End: 2013-05-15T16:00:00.000Z, Description: asdfasdf

Comment: It's just a warnning, and actually I got a new inserted into the datatable.